# Integration test project for Azure Function project

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, integration-testing

I would like to create integration test for Azure Functions. I tried to create host for setup Azure Function, but down with NullReference Exception in Configure method. How could I  setup configuration in integration project context when it execute Configure method?

**Startup.cs**

```
 public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
     {
            base.ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder);

            var configurationBuilder = builder.UseAppSettings()
                .ConfigurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();
            var connectionString = configurationBuilder["appConfiguration"];

            
            // other setup for App Config
     }

     public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
     {
            _configuration = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
            // using that configuration below 
     }
```

**IntegrationHost.cs**

```
 var startup = new MyNamespace.Functions.Startup();
 var host = new HostBuilder()               
          .ConfigureWebJobs((context, builder) =>
           {
               startup.Configure(builder);

           })
           .Build();
```

Comment: Refer this MS Blog -https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/azure-functions-part-2-unit-and-integration-testing/ba-p/3769764 and the codes

Comment: @SiddheshDesai I tried that and created Startup in Integration project. But I have the same issue. On the bottom of that article there is a comment that it doesn't work

Comment: It looks like there are still no proper documentation for isolated functions Azure, But as an alternative can you check this GitHub issue comment by lohithgn and ayayalar here- https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/281

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/281#issuecomment-1019430309

Comment: Also check this GitHub issue and comment- https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/968#issuecomment-1246581416

Answer (score 0):

I tried running this [**Integration Testing Azure Functions sample**](https://github.com/lohithgn/az-fx-isolated-unittest) by lohithgn from this [**github issue**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/281#issuecomment-1019430309) and it ran successfully refer below:-

I cloned the  [**Integration Testing Azure Functions sample**](https://github.com/lohithgn/az-fx-isolated-unittest) sample and ran it locally like below:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Function test app:-**

[image]

Deployed the sample Function from the code in Azure Function app successfully:-

[image]

There's no proper Documentation and known issues while implementing Integration Testing with Isolated Azure Functions.

As a workaround, Also, Try to refer the alternative code from this open [**github issue**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/281#issuecomment-1021311229) by ayayalar

Comment: This sample seems to be for unit testing, not integration testing.